# How can you force StyleCop to ignore a file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-formatting, stylecop

I've included a 3rd party .cs file in my code. It doesn't comply with StyleCop's rules but I desperately need to be able to exclude it from StyleCop's checks but none of the methods I've found so far will work.

Three methods are documented here: http://sethflowers.com/blog/force-stylecop-to-ignore-a-file/ .. but none of these methods seems to work in StyleCop 4.7

The most useful of which looks to be this method in .csproj:

```
<Compile Include="AViolatingFile.cs">
    <ExcludeFromStyleCop>true</ExcludeFromStyleCop>
</Compile>
```

But despite having added the files, StyleCop still causes a compilation error when parsing this file.

Comment: Wait, have you tried **all** of them?

Comment: It's the ExcludeFromStyleCop method I really want to get working as it's the only practical one to implement. The final two methods would involve changing every file, which would break whenever they get updated.  The second method didn't work either.

Comment: Try the third one, as if it works it'd be easy to make a quick program to add it on when it's changed.

Comment: It's the most ugly :( :( :(

Comment: ..and more importantly, why doesn't the official method actually work?

Comment: The method you described works for me, version 4.7.46.1.

Comment: Just a data point from 2016 - ExcludeFromStyleCop works for me with StyleCop.MSBuild nuget 4.7.55 in Xamarin Studio 6.1. I had to use it to suppress the various ...Designer.cs files triggering errors.

Answer (score 35):

```
// <auto-generated/>
```

Put this at the top of the class

Style cop ignores auto generated code

Comment: Typically, third-party code cannot or should not be edited, so this is not useful for this case.

Comment: This does not help if my file is a json file.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone that is still pulling your hair out on this one, I did the following:

.editorconfig

Example:

```
[SpecFlow.Plus.Runner.AssemblyHooks.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1633.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.CS1591.severity = none
```

Comment: This worked for me in JetBrains Rider. I added `.editorconfig` in the root directory with the solution file. Added just the filename in the brackets as above, and changed the severity code (in my case `SA1602`) and saved. Few seconds later the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I used stylecop a while back as well and I believe you have to use the following line in your csproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\StyleCop\v4.6\StyleCop.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\StyleCop\v4.6\StyleCop.targets')" />
```

You will also need to change the version number in the xml declaration to whatever you have installed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a similar line already which I presume does the same thing: (I'm just using a different path for the targets file).

Comment: My line reads:   
`<Import Project="$(ProjectDir)\Integration\StyleCop.targets" />`

Answer (score 1):

Atm, I'm running StyleCop 4.7.49 from Xamarin Studio, and I have some hideous autogenerated file outside of my control (looking at you ¬¬ netfx-System.StringFormatWith)...

The solution for me was to disable all rules for only that file... how to do that?

You have to modify the file `Settings.StyleCop` and insert inside the `StyleCopSettings` tag the following

```
<SourceFileList>
    <SourceFile>HideousClass.cs</SourceFile>
    <Settings>
        <GlobalSettings>
        <BooleanProperty Name="RulesEnabledByDefault">False</BooleanProperty>
        </GlobalSettings>
    </Settings>
</SourceFileList>
```

Change `HideousClass.cs` with the file you want. you can also have multiple `SourceFile` tags if you want to set the rules for various files at once.

Taken from [Using File Lists at StyleCop at CodePlex.com](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20File%20Lists&referringTitle=Documentation) (see "Disable all rules for a subset of files" under "Examples").

Similar approach to the one seen above can be used if you want to enable or disable some rules for only some files.

Comment: CodePlex link is dead. I can't find the migrated equivalent.

Comment: @Reinderien neither do I. [internet archive of dead link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226050757/https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20File%20Lists&referringTitle=Documentation). Evidence [the configuration exists](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/blob/master/Project/Src/StyleCop/Settings/Settings.cs#L263), is [defined in the XML schema](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/blob/master/Project/Src/StyleCop/CoreParser.xml#L30) and [example of use](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/blob/master/Project/Test/Tests.StyleCop.CSharp/TestData/Assorted/TestDescription.xml).

Answer (score -2):

```
// <auto-generated/>
```

put this on top of namespace and that should be good.

Comment: This is a work-around, and not a good one at that. The auto-generated annotations should be only in the auto-generated files.